# How to create div with vertical scroll bar only for long content

Tags: html, css

I want to make div with vertical scroll-bar only for long content without horizontal scroll-bar. I am not familiar with CSS.  Let me know if I am missing anything.

```css
#scroldiv {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 750px;
  height: 1200px;
  background-color: wheat;
}
#iframe {
  width: 803px;
  height: 1000px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1 " runat="server ">
  <div id="scroldiv " style=" ">
    <iframe id="iframe " scrolling="auto " frameborder="0 " onload="window.scrollTo(0, 0) " src="http://www.myhotels24.eu/fibe.aspx?hid=10000&chid=0&rate=IBE&css=brown " allowtransparency="true "></iframe>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: You need not have to post head, title tags of the code unless necessary. When using a snippet you can put the contents of your style tag in CSS section and the contents of body + script tag alone in HTML section (you could also move contents of script tag to JS section and link jQuery lib). Format the code by clicking on "Tidy" button after adding because it improves readability. Include only necessary tags. For this question, JS and jQuery tags don't seem to be required.

Comment: Body tag had an extra ". I had removed it while converting your code into a snippet because it seemed to be a typo and unrelated to your actual question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set `width:100%` to `#scrolldiv` the problem will be solved.

Because the `width` of the `#scrolldiv` was bigger than **parent** `width` the *horizontal scrollbar* was activated for the **parent**.

```css
#scroldiv {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1200px;
  background-color: wheat;
}
#iframe {
  width: 803px;
  height: 1000px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="script/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>


<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div id="scroldiv" style="">
    <iframe id="iframe" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0" onload="window.scrollTo(0, 0)" src="http://www.myhotels24.eu/fibe.aspx?hid=10000&chid=0&rate=IBE&css=brown" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: This works, but a [grid-system](http://www.responsivegridsystem.com) should make it more mobile friendly. You can also use a CSS-Framework, they usually includes some type of grid-system. (I sure you know about this @adricadar, it's just to help ahmeaad more)

Comment: ok that's good it's worked but not in center screen position not in center

Comment: @SebastianHallin it is works good but not in center screen how can i made it center position

Comment: @ahmeaad you can wrap `scrolldiv` in another container, that has a fixed `width` with `margin: 0 auto;`.

Comment: sorry how you can write it here

Comment: @ahmeaad I can do it, but that is another question. I don't want to interfere to current one, to make it more complicated. It's awesome if you can write it yourself and for any problems, you can ask here another question (after you search and struggled to find an answer on your own).

Comment: <div style="width:auto;margin:0 auto;">
        <div id="div1">
            <iframe id="iframe" scrolling="auto" align="middle" frameborder="0" onload="window.scrollTo(0, 0)" src="http://www.myhotels24.eu/fibe.aspx?hid=10000&chid=0&rate=IBE&css=brown" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div> like this i do it is it true

Comment: you want me to update your answer with the new one you told me to add wrap scrolldiv container